# How to show a data list for created profiles

Tags: batch-file

I"m generally new the Batch file and I'm attempting to make an RPG but what I'm looking for goes past my knowledge of Batch file so I was wondering how would I make a system where you would be able to see the profiles/users/data's created then decide what you would do to it Load,Delete,etc.

Data selecting

```
    :DataList
    cls

    echo.
    echo Datas
    echo ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ
    echo TEST
    echo TEST02
    echo TEST03

    set /p Datas=Enter=
    if %Datas% == %CurrentData% goto ?
        ^TEST      ^TEST              ^TESTData
```

So this is what you would see...

```
   Datas
   ---------------
    TEST
    TEST02
    TEST03
```

After you select TESTData

```
    :TESTData
    echo.
    echo TEST Data
    echo ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ
    echo 1) Load Current Data
    echo 2) Delete Current Data
    echo 3) Back

    set /p DataOptions=Enter=
    if %DataOptions% equ 1 goto %TEST%Data
    if %DataOptions% equ 2 then do DEL %TEST%Data
    if %DataOptions% equ 3 goto DataList
```

This is what you would see

```
    TEST Data
    --------------
    1) Load Current Data
    2) Delete Current Data
    3) Back
```

So I basically need to have it operate so that every time you make a new data that it adds it to its function of if %Datas% == %CurrentDatas% and also so that when you choose the data you can delete it.

Comment: Batch is not a suitable game programming language.

Comment: The RPG tag on this site refers to a programming language, not a poorly designated class of computer games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Datas is a dynamic array, you can't hard code them in batch, you have to iterate.

This means you can't use `GOTO :%...%`, as `%...%` is unexpected, and your labels are already written!

Handling arrays in batch isn't easy, but possible. Get sure you have `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` at batch start.

Step 1: show Datas - I assume Datas are files on `profiles/users/data`

```
:DataList
SET DATA_COUNT=0
FOR %%i IN (profiles\users\data\*) DO (
    SET /A DATA_COUNT+=1
    SET %DATA[!DATA_COUNT!]%=%%i
    ECHO !DATA_COUNT!) %%i
)
```

Step 2: get user input

```
SET /P Datas=Enter=
REM Get sure thar %Datas% is a number:
SET /A Datas*=1
IF %Datas% GEQ 1 IF %Datas% LEQ %DATA_COUNT% (
    SET TEST=!DATA[%Datas%]!
    REM Note that from now on, your selected data is stored in %TEST%
    GOTO :TESTData
)
ECHO Invalid option!
PAUSE
GOTO :DataList
```

Step 3: operation on data

```
:TESTData
ECHO TEST Data: %TEST%
ECHO -----------------
ECHO 1) Load Current Data
ECHO 2) Delete Current Data
ECHO 3) Back
SET /P DataOption=Enter=
SET /A DataOption*=1
IF %DataOptions% EQU 1 GOTO :Load_Data
IF %DataOptions% EQU 2 (
    DEL %TEST%
    GOTO :DataList
)
IF %DataOptions% EQU 3 GOTO :DataList
ECHO Invalid option!
PAUSE
GOTO :TESTData
```

Good luck!